# A better way to write: a = b if a is None else a

Tags: python

There is a very common sentence that I use over and over in Python that feels "too long", and I am hoping there is a more Pythonic way to write it:

```
a = b if a is None else a
```

Is there a better way to write this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The typical shortcut for this is

```
a = a or b
```

Though, this will only test if `a` evaluates to `False`, so `0`, `False`, `None`, `''`, etc. will all cause `a` to be set to `b`

Comment: I think is a very dangerous practice, precisely for the reason you state, namely that there are *many* values in python that evaluate to `False`. I'd *much* rather prefer to read `b if a is None else a` than `a or b`, and be left wondering if the intention was really to replace 0 and empty strings with b, or if this is either a bug or someone somehow determined that a will never be zero or the empty string.

Comment: @fgp, It's important to use in the right scenario. And in some cases, this expression is clearer and a better representation of the programmers actual intention than simply testing for `None`. There are many cases where it's expected that only true-ish values are valid. In that case it's useful not to test for just `None`. It doesn't matter whether a user passed in an empty string or `None`, I still don't want those values.

Comment: if a is integer and 0 a possible solution, b is taken by error when a = 0  (not None)

Answer (score 3):

You could do...

```
if a is None: 
     a = b
```

It seems a bit cleaner to me and you don't have to assign a variable to itself.

Comment: `None` testing generally uses `is` rather than equality.

Answer (score 2):

The standard approach is to short circuit as:

```
a = a or b
```

However this is dangerous if its only `None` that you consider needs to be replaced.  For example, if you want to retain values of `a` like `False` then this approach will not do exactly as you desire.

A shorter phrase than your original one, but a rather ugly one, is

```
a = [a, b][a is None]
```

It's not to be recommmended, and can cause some mind-bending to readers, but was a common approach before the introduction of the inline `if ... else ...` syntax

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
a = a or b
```

Python performs short-circuit evaluations, so if `a` evaluates to True (any non-zero integer or float, non-empty lists, non-empty dicts, etc), the value of `a` is return and be is not evaluated.  However, if `a == None`, it evaluates to `False`, so the interpreter must also evaluate `b`.  If `b` evaluates to `True`, then it will be returned as the answer.  There are a couple of cases to watch out for, as mentioned in another answer.

Comment: Rather than telling everyone about the padding, you could tell everyone why trying that should solve the problem. Then you wouldn't have to tell everyone about the padding.

Comment: I smell a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 0):

There sure is: short-circuiting.

```
a = a or b
```